# How to show forms.py file in HTML

Tags: python, django

I've created the forms.py file from the [Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#selectmultiple) tutorial here, But it doesn't show how to display this in HTML. I'm using Django 1.9 and would really appreciate the help. I'm trying to create a question with 4 choices for said question.

Thanks

```
forms.py


Question_CHOICES = (
    ('1', '2', '3', '4',)
)
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    Q1 = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
         required=True, 
         widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, 
         choices=Question_CHOICES
    )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `views.py` file write:

```
def vote_view(request):
    from .forms import QuestionForm
    question_form = QuestionForm()
    return render(request, 'path/to/your/template.html', locals())
```

Then in your HTML write:

```
<div>
    {{ question_form.as_p }}
    or
    {{ question_form.as_table }}
</div>
```

You can render the form in different formats. See [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/#working-with-form-templates).

Also the `locals()` is a python convenient way to pass to the HTML template all the local variables of the current scope (i.e of the `vote_view` view function).

Do not forget, of course to link the view to your base `urls.py` file like this:

```
from your_app.views import vote_view

urlpatterns = [...]  # the previous urls (if any)
urlpatterns += [ url(r'^polls/$', vote_view, name='polls'), ]
```

**[UPDATE]:** The format of your `Question_CHOICES` is wrong for this type of form field. You should to define it this way:

```
Question_CHOICES = (
    ('1', '1'),
    ('2', '2'),
    ('3', '3'),
    ('4', '4'),
)
```

Then is will render to your HTML template either via `{{ question_form }}` or `{{ question_form.as_p }}` or `{{ question_form.as_table }}` or whatever!

Comment: Pretty new to Django,  a novice at best, You still took time out of your day to help me regardless.

Comment: 3 years ago I was in your position. So, I know how you feel. Feel free to ask. Questions never hurt!

Comment: Hi, Your method for displaying in HTML isn't working. Im not sure if it matters but i am using Django 1.9

Comment: Your Django version does not matter. What error do you get? Or you get nothing?

Comment: I'm getting nothing, I had to the remove the locals() you gave in view.py as it was throwing an argument error. but since then neither  {{question_form.as_p }} or  {{ question_form.as_table }} (only one has been used I've tried each one on their own and both) all I'm getting to be shown in the or)

Comment: I have updated my answer. This time it will work. The only thing you have to change is the format of `Question_CHOICES` which should be a tuple of tuples :)

Comment: Again with the help! You're a star, Can confirm this works great!

Comment: Glad I could help. Best regards my friend!

Comment: Hi again, Sorry to be constantly bothering you with this query. But you clearly know your stuff. I'm currently trying to create a button which would save that choice to the database and also take the user to the next HTML page questions. I was going to do this like I've attached in Edit 2. Could you help?

Comment: Sorry to reject your edit on my answer but what you're asking deserves to be written in a separate question. So, please, feel free to ask again!

Answer (score 0):

If you use FBV then you need to create a view_function and initialize the form with your custom form and pass the form to your template via context.

```
1. view.py

    from .forms import QuestionForm

    def custom_view_function(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = QuestionForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                return HttpResponseRedirect('---success url---')
        else:
            form = QuestionForm()

        return render(request, 'template.html', {'form': form})

2. template.html

    <form action="." method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ form }}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

check official django docs for more details [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/)