# How to save to a database on click

Tags: python, django

In my [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42634130/how-to-show-forms-py-file-in-html) question, I recently asked how to make forms.py in Django 1.9 show in HTML. now that this is done im trying to make a button which when the selection has been made (in this case it's radiobuttons) it will post to the database and move on with the questionaire.

Currently im attempting to make it post in my views.py but im having no luck in making it send the data.

```
def question1(request):
    question_form = QuestionForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            return render(request, 'music.questions2,html')
    return render(request, 'music/question1.html', locals())
```

Would really appreciate the help in making this happen.

Comment: Is it really radio buttons or multiple buttons? Remember: radio button allow user to select **ony one** whereas multiple allows... **multiple** ones!

Comment: @nik_m Yes i saw you had Checkboxes for the solution you gave me but Radiobuttons better suited my needs. (not to take away from your help with my query)

Comment: OK! No problem! As both answers bellow, use [`form.save()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method). It implies to have a `form` inherit from `ModelForm`, so that is associatied with a Model. Otherwise, Django will be unable to save the data since it will not know the "connection".

Comment: Okay, That makes sense so the Database is unaware of how to store that information so i need to make a model. models.py to handle the upload? if i understand you correctly?

Comment: Couldn't say it better! More on them [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform)

Comment: Ah Brilliant, is there a way of writing this for Radiobuttons? I was thinking a normal CharField would work, as the Radio buttons will only relate to text?

Comment: Updated my answer to give you a little boost. OK?

Comment: Thank you for the help Nik, I just wanted to ask if I'm linking models to forms for the Meta to work? as I'm getting an Unresolved reference error for it.

Comment: Yes. The whole point of `ModelForm` is to use the `Meta` metaclass to declare the model that this form is "linked" to, via the `model` class attribute. Actually you are not linking models to form but the opposite. Read [the Note at the end of this section](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields) for more.

Comment: Okay great, I appreciate the help thank you @nik_m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def question1(request):
    question_form = QuestionForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()  # save to db!
                return render(request, 'music.questions2,html')
    return render(request, 'music/question1.html', locals())

# models.py
class Question(models.Model):
    # Q_CHOICES is the previous declared one
    question = models.CharField(max_length=20, choices=Q_CHOICES)

# forms.py
class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):
        class Meta:
            model = Question
            fields = ['question']
            widgets = {
                'question': forms.RadioSelect()
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use: form.save()

```
def question1(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = QuestionForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return render(request, 'music.questions2,html')
    else:
        form = QuestionForm()
    return render(request, 'music/question1.html', locals())
```